# LISTAGG oracle function incorrect results

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data

I would like to consult on this problem with aggregation function LISTAGG:

```
select 
r.id, 
(
select
    LISTAGG(
        r.id || '##' || cco.id  
            , 
        ' '
    )
    from 
    (
        SELECT
            co.id
       FROM conditions co
       START WITH ID = (select cons.id from conditions cons where cons.role_id = r.id)
       CONNECT BY PRIOR co.id = co.parent_condition_id
    ) cco
) conditions_export

from roles r
where r.id in (570, 571, 569)
--r.id between 569 and 571



-- table roles has 2 fields: id (number), name (varchar2)
-- table conditions has 4 fields: id, parent_condition_id, role_id (number), rule (varchar2)
```

When I use single id (or explicit ID list) in where condition `r.id in (570, 571, 569)`, result is as expected.

When I don't use where clause, or use some dynamic range (`r.id between 569 and 571`, `r.id > 500`, `r.id in (select rr.id from roles rr)`), result contains the same aggegated value for each row - result is wrong (not as expected).

example from my DB:

values in table roles:

```
id   name
---  -----
569  ROLE1
570  ROLE2
571  ROLE3
```

values in table conditions:

```
id    parent_condition_id   role_id  rule
------------------------------------------
1657  NULL                  569      deny
1659  NULL                  570      allow
1667  NULL                  571      and
1674  1668                  NULL     match
1673  1670                  NULL     allow
1672  1671                  NULL     allow
1671  1670                  NULL     and
1670  1669                  NULL     and
1669  1668                  NULL     and
1668  1667                  NULL     and
```

query: `... r.id in (570, 571, 569)`
result:

```
569 569##1657
570 570##1659
571 571##1667 571##1668 571##1669 571##1670 571##1671 571##1672 571##1673 571##1674
```

query: `... r.id between 569 and 571`
result:

```
569 569##1657
570 570##1657
571 571##1657
```

Reason of using this aggregation is exporting current configuration from database to text file.

Question: do you have any idea, how to work this issue around?

Database version is Oracle 19c

Comment: I don't see your result for `... r.id in (570, 571, 569)` in 18c, 19c (19.16) or 21c; that gets the same as `... r.id between 569 and 571`. But running them individually I can see that should be the result you get from all of them - so I guess you're hitting a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursive subquery factoring instead of a hierarchical query:

```
with rcte (role_id, condition_id) as (
  select r.id, c.id
  from roles r
  left join conditions c on c.role_id = r.id
  where r.id in (570, 571, 569)
  union all
  select rcte.role_id, c.id
  from rcte
  join conditions c on c.parent_condition_id = rcte.condition_id
)
select rcte.role_id,
  listagg(rcte.role_id || '##' || rcte.condition_id, ' ')
from rcte
group by rcte.role_id
order by rcte.role_id;
```

| ROLE_ID | LISTAGG(RCTE.ROLE_ID||'##'||RCTE.CONDITION_ID,'') |
| --- | --- |
| 569 | 569##1657 |
| 570 | 570##1659 |
| 571 | 571##1667 571##1668 571##1674 571##1669 571##1670 571##1673 571##1671 571##1672 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qj4wxL1t) including your various initial queries and their results.

The anchor member gets the role and initial condition; the recursive member then looks for any child conditions.

---

> 1st problem is different order of resulting conditions

Your original code didn't have any ordering of the conditions, so the result is non-deterministic.

In your example output they appear to be ordered by condition ID, so you could just do that explicitly:

```
select rcte.role_id,
  listagg(rcte.role_id || '##' || rcte.condition_id, ' ')
    within group (order by rcte.condition_id) as conditions
from rcte
```

| ROLE_ID | CONDITIONS |
| --- | --- |
| 569 | 569##1657 |
| 570 | 570##1659 |
| 571 | 571##1667 571##1668 571##1669 571##1670 571##1671 571##1672 571##1673 571##1674 |

As you mention the level you might want to order by that, though it gives a different result to your example. You can get the level by tracking a dummy column in the CTE (which I've called `lvl` because `level` is reserved for hierarchical syntax):

```
with rcte (role_id, lvl, condition_id) as (
  select r.id, 1, c.id
  from roles r
  left join conditions c on c.role_id = r.id
  where r.id in (570, 571, 569)
  union all
  select rcte.role_id, rcte.lvl + 1, c.id
  from rcte
  join conditions c on c.parent_condition_id = rcte.condition_id
)
select rcte.role_id,
  listagg(rcte.role_id || '##' || rcte.condition_id, ' ')
    within group (order by rcte.lvl) as conditions
from rcte
group by rcte.role_id
order by rcte.role_id;
```

| ROLE_ID | CONDITIONS |
| --- | --- |
| 569 | 569##1657 |
| 570 | 570##1659 |
| 571 | 571##1667 571##1668 571##1669 571##1674 571##1670 571##1671 571##1673 571##1672 |

Or you could order by level and then condition, where there are multiple conditions at the same level (i.e. several with the same parent); with this data it doesn't make a difference but if there were multiples it would keep it deterministic:

```
select rcte.role_id,
  listagg(rcte.role_id || '##' || rcte.condition_id, ' ')
    within group (order by rcte.lvl, rcte.condition_id) as conditions
from rcte
```

| ROLE_ID | CONDITIONS |
| --- | --- |
| 569 | 569##1657 |
| 570 | 570##1659 |
| 571 | 571##1667 571##1668 571##1669 571##1674 571##1670 571##1671 571##1673 571##1672 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6FEoaVKg?hide=96)

> 2nd problem is I cannot access "LEVEL" variable

The code in your question doesn't refer to it, but as shown above, you can generate it as a `lvl` dummy column. It's unclear how you would use it though - if you want it in the select list then you would have to group by it, which would get a very different result. You could include `max(lvl)` instead; or concatenate the `lvl` into the condition (e.g. `571#1#1667`). It's unclear what you want to do with it.

Comment: thanks for this proposal, it has 2 problems why I cannot use it (so I propably switch to plsql instead of single query). 1st problem is different order of resulting conditions, 2nd problem is I cannot access "LEVEL" variable so I am not able to determine indentation for YAML output

Comment: @tomas - your original query didn't have any explicit ordering, making it non-deterministic, so I didn't add any to mine. I've updated my answer with a couple of ways to order explicitly, depending on the logic you want to apply. I've also shown how to get an equivalent of `level`, but your question doesn't use that either so I'm not sure what you want to do with it.

Comment: thanks, addition of lvl & "within group" order is perfect. I am sorry not to include it in the first question, since I was trying to simplify the problem itself to the minimal version... to have context: I have YAML file with roles... each role has conditions, each condition can have nestad conditions - YAML is processed by spring boot, persisted to oracle. script is intended to recreate YAML with the same order as original and put it to config server with new version... so that's why I use level (nesting of YAML) and order. After your help, mission is successful :)